# Setting selected value in dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Hello every one i have strange bug with dropdownlist on one of the pages!

I used code such as this for 3 dropdownlists:

```
//GetTypes returns collection of all availibale types from database 
      ViewData["Types"] = new SelectList(dataManager.IssueTypes.GetTypes(), "Id", "Title", issue.Type);
```

and it works great!

But when i used it like this:

```
// GetRoles returns collection of all availibale roles
ViewData["Roles"] = new SelectList(dataManager.Membership.GetRoles(), "RoleId", "RoleName",
                dataManager.Membership.GetUserRole(id));
```

it always shows default value!
I looked trough this code with debuger many times but everithing seems fine!
Will be grateful for any kind of help!

View code:

```
%: Html.DropDownList("RoleId", ViewData["Roles"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using view models instead of `ViewData`? Everytime I see someone using `ViewData` I feel myself in the obligation to point this out as personally I consider as best practices.

So start with defining a view model that will be used by your view:

```
public class RolesViewModel
{
    public string SelectedRoleId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's move on to the controller action that will populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string id)
{
    var model = new RolesViewModel
    {
        SelectedRoleId = dataManager.Membership.GetUserRole(id),
        Roles = dataManager.Membership.GetRoles().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.RoleId,
            Text = x.RoleName
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

OK, now you should ensure that `SelectedRoleId` represents a string value which is present in the `Roles` collection. This is what will preselect the dropdown list.

And finally the strongly typed view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedRoleId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Value", "Text")
)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type your dataManager.Membershop.GetUserRole(id) returns?

But you need to change the 4th parameter in this call:

```
ViewData["Roles"] = new SelectList(dataManager.Membership.GetRoles(), "RoleId", "RoleName",
                dataManager.Membership.GetUserRole(id));
```

To something like:

```
ViewData["Roles"] = new SelectList(dataManager.Membership.GetRoles(), "RoleId", "RoleName",
                dataManager.Membership.GetUserRole(id).RoleId);
```

Notice the RoleId at the end? The object you specify as the selected item, should be the value of the item's Value property - not the entire object.

Comment: GetUserRole() returns Role object, strange but it worked before with 4th parametr as object, i trited item's value still no effect